# Better way to combine in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, cartesian-product

I want to combine all elements from one list with all elements from another list, to obtain all possible pairs.

Of course, we can do this in a loop (not tested):

```kotlin
val list1 = listOf(1, 2, 3)
val list2 = listOf('A', 'B', 'C')

val result = mutableListOf<Pair<Int, Char>>()

for (item1 in list1) {
    for (item2 in list2) {
        result.add(Pair(item1, item2))
    }
}

println(result)
```

Is there a better solution with build-in functions like `zip`?

Comment: The term you're looking for is *Cartesian product*. [Rosetta Code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Cartesian_product_of_two_or_more_lists#Kotlin) just does it with for loops. You can also do `flatMap` as Nikolas' answer suggests, but the exact function isn't built-in to Kotlin like it is in some languages.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the additional info!

Comment: [Discussion on Kotlin slack on the same topic](https://slack-chats.kotlinlang.org/t/16314504/hello-all-just-a-quick-question-i-wonder-if-such-a-function-#5b07679f-2fda-45a5-80ea-8b3bd17bfb53)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested, but I guess it should work:

```kotlin
val result = list1.flatMap { item1 ->
    list2.map { item2 ->
        Pair(item1, item2)
    }
}
```